# Add Jbutton to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, calculator

can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code i am trying to add the buttons to my JPanel

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

JPanel createButtonspane(){
   bpanel = new JPanel();
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      buttons.add(new JButton(""+i));
      bpanel.add(buttons);
   }
   return bpanel;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get (this should not even compile)? What are you trying to achieve (why are you creating an Array of JButtons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not compile because `JPanel` does not have an overload of `add()` which takes an array of `JButton`s, so you can not add a whole array of buttons to the `JPanel` (even if it was possible, you would need to do it outside of your `for()`-loop).

Simply add your button directly to the `JPanel`:

```
JPanel createButtonspane(){
   bpanel = new JPanel();
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      bpanel.add(new JButton(""+i));
   }
   return bpanel;
}
```

If you still need to refer to the individual `JButton`s later, add them to the array in addition:

```
JPanel createButtonspane(){
   bpanel = new JPanel();
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      JButton button = new JButton(""+i);
      buttons.add(button);
      bpanel.add(button);
   }
   return bpanel;
}
```